# DataTable Jquery carregar Tools após ajax

Tags: php, ajax, jquery-datatables

Tenho um datatable jQuery que possui a barra tools com .swf. Ao carregar a página inicialmente, a barra tools é exibida corretamente, mas preciso carregar o datatable ao clicar num link, onde o mesmo é preenchido, só que a barra tools não aparece.

O datatable está no arquivo *dados_tabela.php*, chamado por include no arquivo *dados.php*.

Estou chamando o tools por esse código:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    var table = $('#data_table_button').dataTable();
    var tableTools = new $.fn.dataTable.TableTools( table, {
       "Buttons": [
            "copy",
            "csv",
            "xls",
            {
                "sExtends": "pdf",
                "sPdfOrientation": "landscape",
                "sPdfMessage": "Your custom message would go here."
            },
            "print"
        ]

    });

    $(tableTools.fnContainer() ).insertAfter('div.clear');
});
```

A Função `onclick`, para carregar os dados é:

```
function lista_contas(id) {
    var url = 'dados_tabela.php';
    var method = 'POST';
    var params = 'id='+id;
    params += '&select_ano='+document.getElementById('select_ano').value;
    var container_id = 'list_container' ;
    var loading_text = '<img src="img/load.gif">' ;
    // call ajax function
    ajax (url, method, params, container_id, loading_text) ;

    $(document).ajaxComplete(scripts);
}
```